Airflow Virtual Environment (venv) not working, still using global dependencies
I tried to import sqlmodel into one of my DAG using the task.virtualenv decorator, but got error on requirements install because of airflow site-package of sqlalchemy
I tried using the system_site_package=False but still got the problem
The code the code
The error the error

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.
